# Open the instagram app via my app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to open the instagram app from my application and implemented the following code, but it does not do anything. I have instagram app installed on my iphone.

```
NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://app"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:instagramURL];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update `info.plist` for Key **`LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`**

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>instagram</string>
    </array>
```

**Code:**

```
NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://location?id=1"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:instagramURL];
}
```

Refer instagram [docs](https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/)